# Different results in AES256 encryption in Swift (iOS) and PHP

Tags: php, ios, encryption, swift, aes

I am working in AES256 to be able to encrypt/decrypt between iOS and PHP using insecure channels.

I have seen many similar questions that move around the key size, the mode (CBC or ECB), the use of a random iv, etc. But in this case, I found a weird behaviour as follows.

Configuration in both environments:
- Key: 32 bytes(256 bits)
- Block size: 128 bits (standard)
- iv: 16 bytes (static for testing purposes)
- Mode: CBC

If I encrypt a 16 or 32 bytes text (to match the AES block size), the result in Swift, and PHP are similar but not quite the same:

> key         = "12345678901234567890123456789012"
>   plainText   = "12345678901234567890123456789012"
>   iv          = "1234567890123456"
>
> Swift cipher    = e5RnnlJkv4QGnGhkMwfvgMHr80NWUVhbvvfCdPQ5V2KyKJTx4KfWmn4HXi4dG0b8
>   PHP cipher      = e5RnnlJkv4QGnGhkMwfvgMHr80NWUVhbvvfCdPQ5V2I=

As you can see, there is a difference in the cipher length and in the last 2 characters of the PHP Base64 String.

But if I use a text that is not a AES128 Block Size multiplier, let´s say "Hello World", bot environments report different (but same size) ciphers as follows

> Swift cipher    = bdwO/5C8a+pliIoIXtuzfA==
>
> PHP cipher      = oPotHCkxpOwQhIaCz6hNMw==

In both cases (Swift and PHP), the cipher is decrypted correctly regardless of the size of the plaintext.  Also, the Swift results are consistent with the Objective-C version of the code

Attached the simplified code used:

PHP

```
    $key = "12345678901234567890123456789012"; 
    $iv = "1234567890123456";
    $plaintext = "Hello World";
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);
    echo  "ciphertext: ".$ciphertext_base64."</br>";
```

Swift

```
let keyData: NSData! = (key as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
let keyBytes         = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(keyData.bytes)
let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES256)

let plainData = (plainText as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
let dataLength    = UInt(plainData.length)
let dataBytes     = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(plainData.bytes)

var bufferData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
var bufferPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(bufferData.mutableBytes)
let bufferLength  = size_t(bufferData.length)

let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
let options = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

let ivData: NSData! = (iv as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
let ivPointer = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(ivData.bytes)

var numBytesEncrypted: UInt = 0

var cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options, keyBytes, keyLength, ivPointer, dataBytes, dataLength, bufferPointer, bufferLength, &numBytesEncrypted)

bufferData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
let base64cryptString = bufferData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
println(base64cryptString)
```

Why are these different?

Comment: How do you calculate IV?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to padding mode differences.

PHP uses "zero padding" *if* the plain text is not N-times the block size. So PHP pads 0..15 bytes with value `00` for 128 bit block ciphers such as AES. For plaintext that ends on a block boundary it will not add any padding bytes.

Most other languages use PKCS#7 padding, which pads up to the *next* block boundary, where the padding byte reflects the number of bytes added. So that would be 1..16 bytes with a value of 1..16 (or `01` to `10` in hexadecimals). For plaintext that ends on a block boundary it will add 16 bytes of padding.

PKCS#7 padding is deterministic and does not depend on the plaintext value (which could consist of bytes with any value, not just text); in other words, it can always be applied and removed independent of the content.

Zero padding has the issue that plain text ending with `00` bytes may have those `00` bytes removed during unpadding. This is usually not an issue for ASCII compatible strings as `00` is a control character, usually meaning End Of File (EOF).

Please check the comments on `mcrypt_encrypt` to see how you can apply PKCS#7 padding to PHP.

Comment: Note that the underlying `mcrypt` libraries have not been updated since 2007 or so. PHP mcrypt is badly maintained and has horrible samples and documentation (I managed to rewrite the `mcrypt_encrypt` sample code, but now the comments on the code are out of sync).

Comment: Thx @owlstead. I will look into the PKCS#7 padding. But I think that it should not be an issue if the data block size is a multiplier of the AES 128 bits block size (e.g. 16 or 32 bytes). Am I correct?.  If that is the case, do you think that the different cipher size in PHP could be a flaw in the bad maintained, old library?.  Any alternative that you suggest?...

Comment: No, it is. If the size is 16 bytes then PHP won't add any padding. In case of PKCS#7 padding, it will add 16 bytes. Note that I could not decrypt any data with the keys and IV you've indicated, so I could not check the Swift implementation.

Comment: The @owlstead.  2 lines to do the PKCS#7 padding in PHP fixed it.   $padding = 16 - (strlen($plaintext) % 16);   
 $data = $plaintext.str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);

Comment: Hey eharo2 I didn't understand how to fix the problem yet... Where we have to put the last two lines you wrote?

Comment: @fancoolo You apply it to the plaintext (the message) before you provide it to `mcrypt_encrypt` and you perform the reverse operation directly after `mcrypt_decrypt` (removing X bytes from the result, where X is the value of the last byte).

Comment: @fancoolo.   You need to add the 2 lines just before calling the crypt_encrypt() function, as follows:    $padding = 16 - (strlen($text) % 16);     $data = $text.str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);   $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);     I hope it helps..... e

Comment: @eharo2 Same for decrypt?