# AES 256 encryption, difference between PHP/MySQL & Swift

Tags: php, mysql, swift, encryption, aes

I'm trying to obtain the same encryption results (using AES 256) between **PHP/mySQL** and **Swift**.

Here is the text i'm trying to encrypt : **{"email":"aze@aze.com","password":"aze"}**
Here is the key : **toto**
I'm using the SHA1 hash of the key to encrypt : **0B9C2625DC21EF05F6AD4DDF47C5F203837AA32C**

Here is my PHP code (the result is what I expect, I use a local db to perform the encryption)

```
$data = array();
$data['email'] = 'aze@aze.com';
$data['password'] = 'aze';

$json = json_encode($data);
$request = $db->prepare("select AES_ENCRYPT('$json', SHA1('toto')) as data from dual");
$request->execute();
$request->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$encodedResult = $request->fetchAll();
$encodedResult = $encodedResult[0]['data'];

$base64Result = base64_encode($encodedResult));
```

Encoded result is **¤]¼–áú£?îfÞð"2Á«­¯ä%s7Ûš>½qé}‘(J µƒ–"³}vÃë**
Base64 result is **pF28A5bh+qOdP+5mHN7wIjLBBKutr+Qlczfbmj69cel9kRYoShcgtYOWIrN9dsPr**

How can I obtain the same result in Swift or Objective-C ? I tried different libraries such as CryptoSwift / CocoaSecurity, but the result is always different.
It seems that MySQL uses 0 padding, which I can't get to work on iOS.

Edit : To be clear I need to implement 0 padding on iOS side to obtain the same result as MySQL, and not PKCS7 on PHP/MySQL side.

Comment: You're using a database connection solely for executing `AES_ENCRYPT`...!? While being open to SQL injection?! You are aware that you can write equivalent encryption code purely in PHP without the needless overhead of involving MySQL?!

Comment: That is not the point, I'm not using this code or PHP in production. I just want to obtain the same result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different results in AES256 encryption in Swift (iOS) and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980212/different-results-in-aes256-encryption-in-swift-ios-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

With [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) you can easily apply custom padding

```
public struct ZeroPadding: Padding {
    func add(data: [UInt8], blockSize:Int) -> [UInt8] {
        // Padding logic here
    }

    func remove(data: [UInt8], blockSize:Int?) -> [UInt8] {
        // Padding logic here
    }
}
```

and pass it as parameter to `encrypt()`

```
let encrypted = AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC)?.encrypt(message, padding: ZeroPadding())
```